# Toast UILabel appears off screen, despite me setting y correctly

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a Toast extension on a ViewController that inherits `class ViewControllerList: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {` and everything is fine except that when I do this

```
extension UIViewController {

  func showToast(message : String) {
      let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
      let toastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 75, y:  height-100, width: 150, height: 35))
      toastLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
      toastLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
      toastLabel.textAlignment = .center;
      toastLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 12.0)
      toastLabel.text = message
      toastLabel.alpha = 1.0
      toastLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
      toastLabel.clipsToBounds  =  true
      self.view.addSubview(toastLabel)
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
          toastLabel.alpha = 0.0
      }, completion: {(isCompleted) in
          toastLabel.removeFromSuperview()
      })
   }
}
```

the toast ALWAYS appears off screen .. in a long uitableview .. no matter how I set the `y` it always thinks in terms of document.. I have debugged it and `y=676` yet it appears about placement at around ~900 ...100 off the bottom of the tableView just inside the last cell

why is this and how do I fix it?

**Please do not mark this down - TRY to give an answer**

Comment: Try making the local variable `height` equal to `self.view.frame.height` instead of `UIScreen.main.bounds.height`

Comment: it was that, it made no difference, plus I wanted `screen`.. i have actually figured it out - it is because of the `refreshControl` animation effect on `UITableView` pull down.. basically my toast came after a pull down refresh.. the iOS doesn't actually return the display to top after pull down.. so the screen is artificially too long by about 300 px.. is there any way to force it to snap back to the top after drag down? OR at least detect it's screen "effect" y bias?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice you are doing this in a table view! What about adding the toast view to `UIWindow` instead?

Comment: Try something like `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.addSubview(toastLabel)`, instead of the line `self.view.addSubview(toastLabel)`

Comment: @Sweeper can u make this an answer? it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding to `self.view`, add your toast label as a subview of the window:

```
extension UIViewController {

  func showToast(message : String) {
      let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window
      let height = window.bounds.height
      let toastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: window.bounds.width/2 - 75, y:  height-100, width: 150, height: 35))
      toastLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
      toastLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
      toastLabel.textAlignment = .center;
      toastLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 12.0)
      toastLabel.text = message
      toastLabel.alpha = 1.0
      toastLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
      toastLabel.clipsToBounds  =  true

      // notice the change here
      window.addSubview(toastLabel)
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
          toastLabel.alpha = 0.0
      }, completion: {(isCompleted) in
          toastLabel.removeFromSuperview()
      })
   }
}
```

This avoids the problems you have to deal with when the super view is a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new function `addToTopView(view : UIView)` and use like here.

```
extension UIViewController {

    /// adding views as a subview of the top view = window
    func addToTopView(view : UIView) {
        if let d = UIApplication.shared.delegate, let window = d.window! {
            window.addSubview(view)
            // handle constraints or anythings
        }
    }

    func showToast(message : String) {
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        let toastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 75, y:  height-100, width: 150, height: 35))
        toastLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        toastLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        toastLabel.textAlignment = .center;
        toastLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 12.0)
        toastLabel.text = message
        toastLabel.alpha = 1.0
        toastLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        toastLabel.clipsToBounds  =  true
        addToTopView(view: toastLabel) // here is update
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            toastLabel.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {(isCompleted) in
            toastLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
}
```